# kotlin launch - is it ok to launch coroutines in a loop every 1 second

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

i have a custom countdowntimer i created which runs on a background thread. when its updating the results it does so using scope.launch{ // update UI} where this scope is tied to the main thread

is there any implications to calling launch too may times ?

lets take a look at what i have done:

```
class MyClass {

val scopeMain = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())

 fun createTimer() {
  
    Thread {
        Looper.prepare()

        object : CountDownTimer(300000L, 1000L) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                scopeMain.launch {} //update UI here  with the results on main scope ***** is it ok ????
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                scopeMain.cancel()
            }

        }.start() //start the timer

        Looper.loop()
    }.start() //start the  background thread
}
}
```

my point is is there much impact on calling launch like this ...it seems its always on main thread so to me it looks ok, i wanted your opinions. as you can see its continuously being called about every 1 second to launch.

Comment: Why do you even have the background thread? You should be using the main GUI thread. So, except that you don't need it at all, there's nothing wrong with launching these coroutines every second. You could even launch a thousand of them at once and it would still not be a problem.

Comment: yah the team wants absolutly no calculations on the main thread so moving the countdowntimer to background to do work..appreciate the confirmation about launching many coroutines. thanks !!!

Comment: The conventional way to avoid big calculations on the main thread is `withContext(Default) { heavyCalculation() }`. There's really no need to start yet another thread that won't be doing anything but consume memory 99% of the time.

Comment: this was good advice. i've switched it to a scoped coroutine. thanks alot.